# after first time myBatis generator getting lots of "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator, mybatis-mapper

launched for first time myBatis generator using this instructions:
https://mybatis.org/generator/running/runningWithEclipse.html

this is my generatorConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>
  <classPathEntry location="C:/***/ojdbc6.jar"/>
  <context id="context">
    <jdbcConnection
        connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:***:***/***"
        driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        password="***"
        userId="***" />
    <javaModelGenerator
        targetPackage="***.model"
        targetProject="***-dao" />
    <javaClientGenerator
        targetPackage="***.mapper"
        targetProject="***-dao"
        type="XMLMAPPER" />
    <table
        schema="***"
        tableName="USERS">
    </table>
  </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

In eclipse - run as - run myBatis genarator.

Got what I guess is the right code generated, in the right project and package.
Anyway:

- Users.java --> no issues
- UsersDynamicSqlSupport.java --> **lots of erros, for example "SqlColumn cannot be resolved to a type"**
- UsersMapper.java --> **lots of erros, for example "BasicColumn cannot be resolved to a type"**

in my pom I have (related to myBatis) these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

maybe I'm missing something else in pom?
Or other problems, maybe some missing or bad configs in generatorConfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a little of search on internet I found the jar in which are defined those classes, then searched on mvn and found the right dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.dynamic-sql/mybatis-dynamic-sql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```